# Why is my emailSent field writing to row 20 instead of row 2?

Tags: javascript

My code seems to be working properly, except for line 22, which is writing an "emailSent" value to line 20 of the Google Spreadsheet that the script runs against, instead of line 2 of that spreadsheet, which is the only row that has data. Any ideas?

```js
function sendEmails2() {
  //trying to adopt code from this tutorial https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails
  //-believe there is an issue with where I am declaring getRange to work-
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var lastRow = 40;   // Last row of data to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:B10002
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 10)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var i = data.length; 
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[7];  // raised an error at one point 
    var isEmailSent = row[9];     //
    var partTimeApproved = row[0]
    if (partTimeApproved != '') { // prevents sending emails to non-approved rows. for some reason = 'Y' doesn't work but !='' does //... or does it
    if (isEmailSent == '') {  // Prevents sending duplicates and sending emails to non-approved rows
      var subject = "Email Subject Test";
      var message = "Email body test";    // Standard string
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue('emailSent'); //this didn't work: -replacing startRow + i with row-
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  }
}
```

I understand that while the code I am adopting from uses

```
getrange(startRow + i, 10).setValue('emailSent');
```

however, I do not understand how it could be finding row 20 and am not sure how to proceed in fixing it.

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `i` is at that point? I'm guessing 18, since `startRow + i -> 2 + 18 -> 20`

Comment: Marc B Thanks for replying! I agree, but how could it be 18? It comes from:
   var i = data.length; 
   for (i in data) {
So since there is only one row of data, shouldn't it stop at i = 2?

Comment: no, it can be an anything, because in the very next line you're doing `for (i in data)`. e.g. you're trashing the length value with whatever's coming out of the for() loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
var i = data.length; <-- makes no sense
for (i in data) {    <-- since you override i here
```

And I have no clue what data actually is. I am assuming it is an array of strings with numbers. AKA `['0','1']`

So when you are expecting 2 and you are getting 20, it sounds like you are adding a string to a number

```
> 2 + "0"
"20"
```

convert it to a number.

```
> 2 + parseInt("0", 10)
2
```

So in the code:

```
getrange(startRow + parseInt(i, 10), 10).setValue('emailSent');
```

Comment: My code seems to be working with this revision. I am grateful for your edit expanding on your answer as I am glad for the opportunity to learn. I don't understand your first two comments that 'var i=data.length' makes no sense because I override i with 'for (i in data) {'. However, you seem to be correct in that the code does indeed work without that line beginning 'var'.

Comment: Makes no sense in it is useless since you are not using the length in anyway. The next line you just override the value with new content.